# Custom Association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am finding it hard to understand some of the association defined in the code base.

```
class Patient < ApplicationRecord   
    belongs_to :g_district, class_name: "District", primary_key: "id", foreign_key: 'district_id', optional: true
    belongs_to :g_perm_district, class_name: "District", primary_key: "id", foreign_key: 'permanent_district_id', optional: true
    belongs_to :g_workplc_district, class_name: "District", primary_key: "id", foreign_key: 'workplace_district_id', optional: true    
end
class District
    belongs_to :province #, optional: true
    belongs_to :division, optional: true
    has_many :hospitals
    has_many :tehsils
    has_many :ucs
    has_many :mobile_users
    has_many :labs
    has_many :insecticides
end
```

I am not clearly getting these kind of associations defined her.(belongs_to :g_district, class_name: "District", primary_key: "id", foreign_key: 'district_id', optional: true).

In my code, there are no models like g_district, g_perm_district, g_workplc_district.

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to ... apart from the fact that you have a `class_name` defined such that `X.lab` would return the associated `Hospital` (linked via the `lab_id` in X to the `id` in `Hospital`) everything seems normal in that link ... If you could edit your question to add in the code for the 2 models you're working with, I could give specific answers

Comment: @Jad please have a look now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

```
belongs_to :lab,          # instances will belong to one `lab`
  class_name: "Hospital", # but the model is not called `Lab` but `Hospital`
  primary_key: "id",      # primary key is `hospitals.id` (actually not needed)
  foreign_key: 'lab_id',  # the foreign key is `lab_id` (again not needed)
  optional: true          # okay when there is no lab assign (default: required)
```